# Google Pub/Sub pull method restart express server after every 1 min

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using pun/sub to pull messages when someone buys a subscription from google play.

```
const { PubSub } = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
const grpc = require('grpc');
// Instantiates a client
const pubSubClient = new PubSub({ grpc });

const  pubsub  = () => {
  const projectId = process.env.GOOGLE_PUB_SUB_PROJECT_ID; // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
  const subscriptionName = process.env.GOOGLE_PUB_SUB_SUBSCRIBER_NAME; // Name of our subscription
  const timeout = 60;
  const maxInProgress = 10;

  const subscriberOptions = {
    flowControl: {
      maxMessages: maxInProgress,
    },
  };

  // Get our created subscription
  const subscriptionPub = pubSubClient.subscription(subscriptionName, subscriberOptions);
  console.log(`subscription ${subscriptionPub.name} found.`);

  // Create an event handler to handle messages
  let messageCount = 0;

  // Create an event handler to handle messages
  const messageHandler = message => {
    console.log(`Received message: ${message.id}`);
    console.log(`Data: ${message.data}`);
    console.log(`Attributes: ${JSON.stringify(message.attributes)}`);
    //todo: you can update your backend here using the purchase token
    
    messageCount += 1;

    // "Ack" (acknowledge receipt of) the message
    message.ack();
  };

  // Create an event handler to handle errors
  const errorHandler = function (error) {
    console.log(`GOOGLE PUB SUB ERROR: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  };

  // Listen for new messages/errors until timeout is hit
  subscriptionPub.on('message', messageHandler);
  subscriptionPub.on('error', errorHandler);

  setTimeout(() => {
    subscriptionPub.removeListener('message', messageHandler);
    subscriptionPub.removeListener('error', errorHandler);
   console.log(`${messageCount} message(s) received.`);
  }, timeout * 1000);
};
module.exports = pubsub;
```

And above file is called in the main.js file and every 1 min I am receiving log **subscription ${subscriptionPub.name} found**.

also, I have commented setTimeout code as of now but I want to understand why removeListener is important to remove the listener every one minute.

Comment: The timeout to remove the listener is for not having an infinite loop that listen all the time. If you want to listen the subscription full time, remove the setTimeout part. What do you want to have at the end?

Comment: Could you share what you want to achieve and an overview of your process? Also, have you followed any tutorial?

Comment: So the idea is when any subscription from the android play store expires or renews a particular subscription we update a new state into our database. For that, we have used the pub/sub pull method. Let me know is the correct way to do it? @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes check the above comment to have an idea.

Comment: TLDR: remove the setTimeout code.

You can remove the setTimeout code if you want to continuously listen for messages and errors. You probably want to keep processing data until shutdown, right? To clean up the subscriber listener cleanly, you may want to call removeListener on shutdown; this isn't really necessary however, since any unacked messages will be resent once your subscriber is back online.

Comment: @PradNelluru yes I have commented setTimeout code. but also I want to understand why I am receiving `console.log("subscription ${subscriptionPub.name} found.");` after every one minute. Is this because of setTimeout? I have called that function on the root of the project and because of that 
```const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port ${port}");
});```
this is also being called.

Comment: Why do not simply use a push subscription and plug a serverless service in front to process the messages?